# Old cartoon where the main guy and his friends capture monsters and fuse them

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

This is an old cartoon from 15 years ago or more, where a guy and his friends capture monsters in the real world, and after capturing the monsters, they fuse them to create even better monsters. They use some device like in *Digimon* to capture the monster and fuse them.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Can you describe the appearance and sex of the main characters? Also, please take a look at the check lists in this [this thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), and if they help you to recall any other details, [edit] your question to include those additional details. The more info you can provide, the greater the likelihood that someone can ID this for you.

Comment: I know what you mean I think I know the show and the main character was male and he had a group of buddy and they would challenge someone to a fight in a zone and catch little monster then after the time was up they would use the monsters to fused into big monster and there were 5 elements fire, wind, earth, water and nature a think

Answer (score 2):

Could this be ***[Mix Master](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2035145/)*** (2005-2006)...?

From IMDB:

> The town of Gamebridge has mixed up with a magical game world. Monsters are running wild, and an evil prince is plotting world conquest. The folks of Gamebridge must turn to an unlikely hero who will save the world.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mix_Master):

> *Mix Master* (Korean: 카드왕 믹스마스터; RR: *Kadeu Wang Mikseu Maseuteo*; Japanese: カード王 ミックスマスター) is a South Korea–Japan co-produced anime series based on the massively multiplayer online role-playing game *Mix Master: King of Cards*. It is a co-production of Nippon Animation Japan and Sunwoo Entertainment and KBS of Korea. The series aired on Cartoon Network in many Asian areas from the Far East to the Middle East. The story centers on the fantasy and adventure card game, Mix Master.

> **The series takes place in the town of Gamebridge where, through the accidental opening of a portal from the fictional Mix Master video game world of Atreia, the peaceful little town is invaded by the funny and sometimes dangerous game creatures, known as "hench", as well as the game world's evil Prince Brad. The main protagonist, 11-year-old Ditt Lee, is given a card shuffler by the eccentric Dr. Joeb, and now must "mix" those hench (as learned from the fictional video game) to achieve peace and safety, while he grows into his destiny to become the one true "Mix Master".**
>
> **The series presented over two hundred henches from different species. They can be fused or 'mixed' together to form a new, stronger hench.** Henches are ranked from 1 (low) to 7 (high) depending on their power. Animals and plants are present. To be mixed, henches must be of the same rank and species. Henches are shown to be like humans, as they can sleep, eat, talk and tire out if they are overused. They bond with humans who show honesty and friendship. They have to obey the orders of the person who owns their card shuffler, even against their will. They seem to grow old and die.
>
> Although Henches are ranked as high as 7, above level 7 one hench is known as the Ultimate Hench and is the most powerful. Ultimate Hench exists when all the 8 Henches of Rank 7 are fused with the help of the Mix Master and The Master Hench. According to legend, the Master Hench has to find one human friend whom it trusts above all else, and that human becomes the Mix Master. It appears that the Master Henches are somehow related, as Pachi's brother was the previous Master Hench. The Master Hench can be mixed to become the ultimate Hench that can defeat Giara.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is called "battle claw" I remember it being very similar to what you are talking about

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You should [edit] your answer to note specific elements that match the question, as well as anything that doesn't fit.  Also, how old is it?  The show *BattleClaw* dates only to 2017.